# How to update specific item in paging list

Tags: android, android-paging

I am using a paging library for android to load data from a web server and show it in a list.

Facing a problem with "add to favorites" functionality. To do so, I have to send a pull request to my webserver after which I have to update that specific item in my paged list, to show a difference in UI to denote that the item is added to Favorites.

I've tried `dataSource.invalidate()` method, but it refreshes the whole list. I can't update this specific item directly in the list as the paging library doesn't provide me access to the list directly.

How can I refresh one single item from paged list?

```
class AdsDataSource(
        private val token: String?,
        private val categoryUrl: String?,
        private val subcategoryUrl: String?,
        private val fullPath: String?,
        private val lang: String,
        private val apiV2: APIV2,
        private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, AdsListParent>() {
private val pLoadAdsStatus = MutableLiveData<ELiveDataStatuses>(ELiveDataStatuses.IDLE)
    val loadAdsStatus: LiveData<ELiveDataStatuses> = pLoadAdsStatus

    private val pLoadAdsError = MutableLiveData<Throwable?>(null)
    val loadAdsError: LiveData<Throwable?> = pLoadAdsError

    private var retryCompletable: Completable? = null

override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, AdsListParent>) {
        pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.WAITING)

        val adsRequest = apiV2.getAdsBySubcategory(categoryUrl, subcategoryUrl, token, INITIAL_PAGE, PAGE_SIZE, lang)
        compositeDisposable.add(
                adsRequest
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .map { adsFromSubcategory ->
                            adsFromSubcategory
                                    .mapToAdsListParent()
                                    .toMutableList()
                                    .apply {
                                        if (size >= AD_LIST_MIN_SIZE)
                                            add(AD_LIST_MIN_SIZE, AdsListParent.AdsListAd(adsFromSubcategory.admixerAndroid))
                                    }
                                    .toList()
                        }
                        .subscribe({
                            retryCompletable = null

                            pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.DONE)

                            pLoadAdsError.postValue(null)

                            callback.onResult(it, null, INITIAL_PAGE.inc())
                        }, {
                            pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.ERROR)

                            pLoadAdsError.postValue(it)

                            retryCompletable = Completable.fromAction {
                                loadInitial(params, callback)
                            }
                        })
        )
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, AdsListParent>) {
        pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.WAITING)
        val adsRequest = apiV2.getAdsBySubcategory(categoryUrl, subcategoryUrl, token, params.key, PAGE_SIZE, lang)
        compositeDisposable.add(
                adsRequest
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe({
                            retryCompletable = null

                            pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.DONE)

                            pLoadAdsError.postValue(null)

                            callback.onResult(it, params.key.inc())
                        }, {
                            pLoadAdsStatus.postValue(ELiveDataStatuses.ERROR)

                            pLoadAdsError.postValue(it)

                            retryCompletable = Completable.fromAction {
                                loadAfter(params, callback)
                            }
                        })
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: Ok, but I thought it's enough to describe my problem, there is nothing interesting in code, it's default implementation of pagination in android

Comment: Please edit the question and share the code there. The code in the comment is not readable and is not complete.